# Remove "series 1" text in highcharter map tooltip

Tags: r, highcharts, tooltip, r-highcharter

In my interactive highcharter map, I would like to get rid of the text in the tooltip that says "Series 1" and instead have that part be blank. I would also like to remove the colon and 1 following the country name. How can I do this? I would still like to keep the country name in the tooltip.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KLKG.png)

Here is my code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(maps)

countrylabeldata<-iso3166

countrylabeldata <- rename(countrylabeldata, "iso-a3" = a3)

Swahili_countries <- c("BDI","COD", "KEN", "OMN", "RWA", "TZA", "UGA")

countrylabeldata$include <- ifelse(countrylabeldata$`iso-a3` %in% Swahili_countries, 1, 0)


hcmap(
  map = "custom/world-highres3", 
  data = countrylabeldata, 
  joinBy = "iso-a3",
  value = "include",
  showInLegend = FALSE,
  nullColor = "#DADADA",
  download_map_data = TRUE,
) %>%
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = T) %>%
  hc_legend("none") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Countries with Highest Prevalence of Swahili Speakers")%>%
  hc_caption(text="Data from CIA World Factbook")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the "Series 1", set the variable "name" to a blank space, i.e. `name = ""`. As for the : 0 and : 1, you can get rid of that by deleting the variable `value = "include"` in hcmap, but it will get rid of the specific countries you have highlighted. Do you want to preserve the countries highlighted on the map? Someone probably has a more efficient answer than I do.

Here is how I edited your code:

```
hcmap(
 map = "custom/world-highres3", 
 data = countrylabeldata, 
 joinBy = "iso-a3",
 showInLegend = FALSE,
 value = "include",
 nullColor = "#DADADA",
 name = "",
 download_map_data = TRUE) %>%
hc_mapNavigation(enabled = T) %>%
hc_legend("none") %>%
hc_title(text = "Countries with Highest Prevalence of Swahili Speakers")%>%
hc_caption(text= "Data from CIA World Factbook")
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes, I would like to preserve the countries that are highlighted on the map.